# Function wrapper around firestore function not returning results (Firestore & Vue)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in a util file I call "FbUtils.js":

```
getUserById(someUserId) {
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(someUserId)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    const res = { userId: someUserId, data: snapshot.data() };
    console.log(res); // WORKS!!! 
    return res;
  });
}
```

And in a Vue component, I import the function and create a button specifically to test this function:

```
methods: {
  test() {
    var testResults = FbUtils.getUserById("someHashString");
    console.log(testResults);
  }
}
```

But every time I press the button, "Undefined" is printed on the console log. It's really hard to debug to me because the console.log(res) before getUserById() returns prints the correct object. But console.log(testResults) prints "Undefined". What could be wrong here? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the Firestore query is asynchronous and returns immediately, you should make `getUserById` return a promise the resolves with the data to return, then have the caller use that promise to know when the query results are ready.

```js
getUserById(someUserId) {
  return firebase // return the promise chain
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(someUserId)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const res = { userId: someUserId, data: snapshot.data() };
      console.log(res); // WORKS!!! 
      return res;
    });
}

methods: {
  test() {
    FbUtils.getUserById("someHashString").then(testResults => {
      console.log(testResults);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! It works. I'm curious as to why an additional `.then()` is necessary. Doesn't the `then()` in `getUserById()` already wait for the query to complete before returning?

Comment: No.  then() just returns another promise that resolves when the entire chain is complete.